# AngularJS: how to display many results from many checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, angular-ngmodel

I'm using AngularJS to filter the results of a wine's list. The wines are categorized by colors (red, white, rose, champagne), and other parameters.

When one color is checked with the check-box (red for example), a filtered list of red wine appears. But when two colors are selected, no results appears (red and white for example).

**my wishes:**

- Even If the red, white, and champagne colors are checked, would appears the list of the (red, white, and champagne wines, or other parameters). My principal wish, would be to able to choose more than one parameter, and display all the checked ones. Be able to check the colors, the countries..

here the code example:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<input ng-model="characteristics.red" type="checkbox" >red</input>
<input ng-model="characteristics.white" type="checkbox" >white</input>
<input ng-model="characteristics.rose" type="checkbox" >rose</input>
<input ng-model="characteristics.champagne" type="checkbox" >champagne</input>
    <br><br>

<div ng-repeat="wine in filtered= (wines |filteredstoves:characteristics) |       filteredstoves:characteristics">

    {{wine.name}} - {{wine.characteristics}}
        </div>
    <br><br>
     Filtered list has {{filtered.length}} items
</div>
```

**Demo of the code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos/kTYdd/26/

regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your filter like this:

```
.filter('filteredstoves', function() {
  return function(stoves, characteristics) {
    var result = []; 
    angular.forEach(characteristics, function(value, key) {
      if(value) {
        for(var index = 0; index < stoves.length; index++) {
          var wine = stoves[index];
          if(wine.characteristics.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
            if (result.indexOf(wine) === -1){
                result.push(wine);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RUFdy/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your very fast reply!! I've just tried, and it works very fine!! I tried hours, i didn't have success.... Thanks a lot Khanh TO!!

Comment: Thanks for the help..... It is possible to filter the result. I added more, if it checked "red" and "leger", appears all the entries with red and leger, it's not filtered. Same things if i check champagne and leger. http://jsfiddle.net/stefanos/RUFdy/4/

Comment: @Stéphane: what is the problem? I don't get it

Comment: My english is not so good. My wish is, for example : if the red checkbox and leger are both checked, would be displayed  a list only with the entries red wines with the leger parameters, and not the other entries that contains too leger or red.   It sounds hard to establish a code to filter all these parameters. Regards

Comment: Thanks again!  In fact,  if red and fort are checked , i would to display only the wines red and fort.  If red and white and leger are checked,  i wish to see only the red and white wines on the list that contains leger. I wish to build a selective filter,  each checkbox filter selected will display an unique characterisc,  2 checkbox selected 2 uniques characteristic,  and so on...... regards!

Comment: @Stéphane:sorry but I still don't get what you mean. Can you ask that as a separate question so that you could draw more attention from other people, too? In that question, you can give examples, context,.. to make it clearer. And this is what you should do on SO http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-is-annoying-me-by-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was

Comment: Hi Khanh To, thanks for your advice. I will ask as a separate question, and make it clearer!!

Comment: my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107781/build-a-dynamic-multi-parameter-filter-list-with-angularjs

Comment: Because of you advice, to make it clearer, give me very good result! Thanks again for your help!